What prehistoric or shamanic art does this guitar recall?
A colleague of mine is making a little guitar to put on his wall, following a design he found online (not sellable, we know).
The guitar manufacturer means to evoke moon slivers, but to me the outline looks just like a certain figure that should be Stone Age or perhaps Native American? Or perhaps I saw it in an esoteric context, brightly colored.
Reverse image search as well as some searches for human figures aren't turning it up. Can you identify what I'm thinking of? Should be really close in shape, not merely my idiosyncratic association.


It reminds me of designs for tribal tattoos, fantastical battle axes, and Klingon objects :) But it also seems too ubiquitous a shape to identify—can you tell us what your underlying purpose is? Or is it just because it's annoying to almost know something but not being able to grasp it?

@Joachim Right, it's for curiosity of a few people who know what I mean but can't name it.

Your calling it ubiquitous surprises me. How do mean that?

Just that I think (and I am not familiar with that side of rock music) that this shape, while likely being unique in dimensions and specific curvature, seems 'typical' of a kind of guitar design.

@Joachim I was so sure in the beginning but it turned out both moot and unenlightening. I figure I ought to delete my own question, what do you think?

Anti-climactic answers are not uncommon on this platform, and questions shouldn't be judged by their answers. I agree it probably isn't particularly useful for others, but that's completely fine, too. I think you can just leave it :)

Alright, thanks for the guidance.

I'm sorry folks, what was on my mind is the logo of German band Einstürzende Neubauten. One has to admit it's very archaistic ;)


Haha, yeah, that does seem similar. But with the arms pointing down :)
